# Nonfunctioning keyboard interrput

Tags: python-2.7

I have a python script with many problems, but the root cause of all of them is it wont react to the keyboard interrupt. I'm guessing the problem is either that I am using SSH *only* to connect or that I am using threads. Here it is as MCV as I could make it:

```
from threading import Thread           
import time, random                                                                                                                                             

def distance():                                                                                                                                                     
    while True:                                                                                                                                                         
        print "hi"                                                                                                                                              

def drive():                                                                                                                                                       
    while True:                                                                                                                                                         
        print "hi"                                                                                                                                               

distance = Thread(target=distance)                                                                                                                              
drive = Thread(target=drive)                                                                                                                                    
distance.start()                                                                                                                                                
drive.start()
```

If I stop it using `kill PID` it stops but I don't want to have to do that all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply "unhook" `SIGINT` in Python so that it reverts to the default system behavior, which is to end the process:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

Do that before starting your threads, and then Ctrl-C, rather than generating KeyboardInterrupt, will simply terminate the program.

Comment: The problem is I need it to trigger an exception to run `pz.cleanup` (in the final program) otherwise the motors I am using will just keep turning. While this is useful I don't think it would work for my purposes.

Comment: @sir_ian: In that case, simply define a cleanup function that does whatever you need on shutdown, and pass that function to `signal.signal()` in place of `SIG_DFL`.

Comment: genius (filler)

Comment: what do you mean by pass function? `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, kill_function())`?

Comment: @sir_ian: No parens, just `signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, kill_function)`.  Look at the docs for `signal.signal`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.signal